# When using add(), how to keep batch open until the loader loop class finishes?

Tags: laravel

I am adding jobs to a batch in a loop that is fed from an (3rd party) api. It sometimes loads all data and sometimes it takes time to get the data and the batch closes before the whole data is fetched.

```
    do {
        $page++;
        $response = $api->getProducts(['page'=>$page])->json();

        foreach ($response['products'] as $product) {
            $batch->add(new \App\Jobs\ProcessJob($product));
        }

        $total_pages = $response['params']['total_pages'];
    } while ($page < $total_pages);
```

It seems like in some cases the \App\Jobs\ProcessJob works faster than the the feeding class and the batch closes before the feeder adds all the needed data. How can I keep the batch open until the feeder class finishes feeding till the last page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some sifting around, I found out the batch actually does not close itself. My setting in queue config retry_after was set to short and the job running the batch was timed out by that setting. Now it does not timeout and works till the end.